# MySQL: Update with count of another table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a column in one table, with the count of another table so I don't have to do multiple selects for easy access to this information, although it is not working as expected. It seems to be fetching the total count of the table.

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE `profile_data` SET `post_count` = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `profile_post_media` 
    WHERE `post_id` = (SELECT `post_id` 
                       FROM profile_posts 
                       WHERE `profile_posts`.`profile_id` = profile_data.profile_id)
);
```

Comment: What is the output from `SELECT COUNT(*) ....` statement? It probably is " total count of the table"...

Comment: @Luuk yes, the total number of rows in `profile_post_media` table.

Answer (score 0):

I can to advice next approach:

```
UPDATE `profile_data`
-- join pre-calulated counts
JOIN (
    -- calculate post count for each profile
    SELECT
      `profile_id`, COUNT(*) `post_count` 
    FROM `profile_posts` 
    GROUP BY `profile_id`
) `counts` ON `counts`.`profile_id` = `profile_data`.`profile_id`
-- update data using pre-calculated table
SET `profile_data`.`post_count` = `counts`.`post_count`
;
```